# Correct response is returned only after second attempt while generating JWT

Tags: php, lumen, laravel-socialite

I am trying to use [Socialite](https://github.com/laravel/socialite) and [JWT](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) together, however I am facing with some issues.

My goal is to update user's `profile_image_url` field in database if user already exists and give him token, if user doesn't exist, then create it and also give him token.

This is what I am doing right now:

```
public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request){

        try{
            $providerUser = Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->userFromToken($request->fb_token);

            $user = User::query()->firstOrNew(['email' => $providerUser->getEmail()]);
          }catch(Exception $e){
              return new JsonResponse(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Woops, some error happened']);
          }

          if(!$user->exists){
            $user->name = $providerUser->getName();
            $user->profile_image_url = $providerUser->getAvatar();
            $user = $user->save();
          }else{
              $user->update(['profile_image_url' => $providerUser->getAvatar()]);
          }

          $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);

          return $this->onAuthorized($token, $user);
     }
```

And this is what I am returning onAuthorized:

```
protected function onAuthorized($token, $user){
        return new JsonResponse([
            'status' => '40002',
            'message' => 'Successfully logged in with facebook',
            'user' => [
                'user_id' => $user->id,
                'name' => $user->name,
                'email' => $user->email,
                'profile_image_url' => $user->profile_image_url,
                'token' => $token
            ]
        ]);
    }
```

But this gives me the following error on first try if user doesn't exist, even tho it saves the user into the database:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to Tymon\JWTAuth\JWT::fromUser() must
>   implement interface Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject, boolean given,
>   called in
>   /var/www/goodzapp.com/api/vendor/illuminate/support/Facades/Facade.php
>   on line 221

What I am doing wrong? Can someone please explain me. Any help would be much appreciated.